# How to hold the socket instance on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io, real-time

on my root component I am setting up the the socket like this,

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
const setupSocket = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('CC_Token');
    if (token && token.length > 0 && !socket) {
      const newSocket = io('http://localhost:8000', {
        query: {
          token: localStorage.getItem('CC_Token'),
        },
      });

      newSocket.on('disconnect', () => {
        setSocket(null);
        setTimeout(setupSocket, 3000);
        makeToast('error', 'Socket disconnected!');
      });

      newSocket.on('connect', () => {
        makeToast('success', 'Socket Connected');
      });

      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setupSocket();
  }, []);
```

and using react-router I am passing the socket instance as a prop.

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/chatroom/:id"
  render={() => <ChatroomPage socket={socket} />}
/>;
```

it works fine until, I refresh the page. when I refresh the page socket gets back to its initial state (null) so that, I can not send any message.

This snippet is from `CharoomPage` component.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.emit("joinRoom", {
        chatroomId,
      });
    }

    return () => {
      //Component Unmount
      if (socket) {
        socket.emit("leaveRoom", {
          chatroomId,
        });
      }
    };
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

On page refresh socket is null, so It can not emit the `joinRoom` event.

How can I implement this so that on page refresh I emit the `joinRoom` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you refresh the page, socket will go back to initial state `null` and the `useEffect` should run.

But your ChatRoomPage useEffect do not take `socket` into the second arguments.

Try with

```
const ChatRoom = ({socket}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if( !socket) return;

    socket.emit("joinRoom", {chatroomId});
    return () => {
      if (!socket) return;
      socket.emit("leaveRoom", {chatroomId});
    };
  }, [socket]); //<== here
};
```

The strange part of your bug is that it sometime works before refresh.